# Apple keeps resetting my Apple ID password?

Tags: apple-id

For the last 4 weeks or so, I get the "This apple ID has been disabled for security reason... bla bla bla" notification at least two times per week. All my devices are up to date and have been updated to use the new password.

There are at least 5 people in my office that are experiencing the same problem. I have read the article @ http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2446 but it doesn't help me much.

How can I make them stop? I will run out of passwords very, very soon.

Comment: Are you a developer who is using AppAnnie to track App Store sales?

Comment: anthonyg, I'm a developer, but this is on my private account not our developer accounts

Comment: Ok, I was asking because App Annie had a problem which meant that many developers got their accounts locked and had to reset.

Answer (score 6):

It might be the case that someone is trying to gain access to your and your coworkers accounts by trying out random passwords. After a certain number of failed attempts, your account will be disabled to prevent bad guys from continuously trying out passwords.

My suggestion would be to try to find out why it is being reset by contacting Apple support. They can probably tell you the specific reasons for disabling the account as it will probably be logged by them.

Sorry to redirect you, but this is not something we can 'solve' without knowing the reason behind the resets :-)

Answer (score -3):

*They* have your email address and pasword. I would recommend to change email password and iTunes password in these situations.

Comment: While changing passwords is advisable in general, it doesn't really help to solve the problem stated in the question. The asker has to assign a new password anyway to get access again. In addition: Who is "they"?